# How to get most recent documents in .NET NEST 2.xx?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

My index contains millions of documents with a Datetime field correctly set.

I have the code below but it does not return (sort) the most recent documents, instead it returns some documents of older dates.

```
            var r = client.Search<Topic>(s => s
                .From(from)
                .Size(size)
                .MatchAll()
                .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p=>p.Datetime))
             );
```

Remark : my field is well mapped to "Date" type in the class and I've well AutoMap() the properties at the creation of the mapping :

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "Topic")]
public class Topic
{
    [Date()]
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Any idea please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a small succinct example to demonstrate? It sounds like you may be searching for just indexed documents before the refresh interval. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html

Comment: Thank you Russ for your reply. But this is not the case. Documents are well in the index for weeks. Will try to test on fewer items and copy json data to this thread...